# How can I redirect to a View in a different Solution in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I would like to redirect the User in Application 1 to a View that is in Application 2.

Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult RedirectUser(string applicationName)
    {
        switch (applicationName.ToLower())
        {
            case "app1":
            case "app2":
            case "app3":
            case "app4":

       return RedirectToAction("Index", applicationName);
            default:
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserApplication");
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you thought about authentication? how will you authenticate that user? are you doing any authentication? if not i think you can use cookies...  or store session in a db. someone correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This redirection happens only after authentication.  But the user needs to be redirected to another Application - not sure how to qualify the View - something like /AnotherApplication/View/Index...

Comment: are these applications part of the same solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a Redirect(url) and storing the urls in configuration.